# InfluxDBClientError: 400: {"error":"error parsing query: found -06, expected ; at line 1, char 35"}

Tags: python, influxdb-python

I am using influxdbClient to query the Influxdb through python.

the simple query works well as:

`from influxdb import InfluxDBClient`

`client = InfluxDBClient(host='192.168.1.104', port=8086)`

`client.get_list_database()`

`client.switch_database('Mlogi_ALL')`

`res= client.query('SELECT * FROM n')`

But when I query :

`client.query('SELECT * FROM n WHERE (time >= 2018-06-01T00:00:00Z AND time <= 2018-07-30T00:00:00Z')`

it gives error :

> InfluxDBClientError: 400: {"error":"error parsing query: found -06, expected ) at line 1, char 36"}

where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it's valid when you pass date value directly like `time >= 2018-06-01T00:00:00Z`

But for your sql,you are missing `)` at the end of your sql,so change

```
client.query('SELECT * FROM n WHERE (time >= 2018-06-01T00:00:00Z 
       AND time <= 2018-07-30T00:00:00Z')
```

to

```
client.query('SELECT * FROM n WHERE (time >= 2018-06-01T00:00:00Z 
    AND time <= 2018-07-30T00:00:00Z)')
```

Note: in your sql you can also remove `()` after `WHERE`